# Did the user post count and badges just disappear from questions?

Tags: support

You can only see the user's handle, and the postcount doesn't show up when you hover over it. The badges disappeared too.

Is this some attempt at equalizing things, so that there are no more postcounts or badges and all questions and answers and users are equal?

The badges are clutter, but the postcount on hover for me is a quick way to check the "assumed understanding" of a person. After all, it makes a huge difference whether the user has 10 points or 1000 points. The new user feature doesn't help here, because there are old profiles with new profile-level questions.

Ah, postcount on hover was/is for comments, it was visible in the avatar area previously (with the badges).

Comment: I was about to post the same question. Reproduced in Firefox - logged in, and private browsing.

Comment: Same in Chrome.